# Get image from imageview using android accessibility

Tags: android, image, imageview, accessibility, accessibilityservice

Is it possible to obtain the image from imageviews using android accessibility? I am getting the texts from edittext and textview but could not get image from imageviews. On printing the AccessibilityNodeInfo (named as root) using `Log.d("IMAGE",root.toString());`, I got this:

```
   D/IMAGE: android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo@8001bc92; 
boundsInParent: Rect(0, 0 - 102, 96); 
boundsInScreen: Rect(933, 0 - 1035, -210); 
packageName: com.android.systemui; 
className: android.widget.ImageView; 
text: null; 
error: null; 
maxTextLength: -1; 
contentDescription: Brightness settings panel; 
viewIdResName: null; 
checkable: false; 
checked: false; 
focusable: true; 
focused: false; 
selected: false; 
clickable: true; 
longClickable: false; 
contextClickable: false; 
enabled: true; 
password: false; 
scrollable: false; 
actions: [AccessibilityAction: ACTION_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SELECT - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLEAR_SELECTION - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLICK - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_NEXT_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_PREVIOUS_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SET_SELECTION - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SHOW_ON_SCREEN - null]
```

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Comment: is there any solution to it as of 2023?

Comment: @algodextrous I don't think it is possible, maybe taking a screenshot can help, or reading the image resource address. but we can't get the image from the UI as a bitmap. at least I couldn't

Answer (score 0):

you can set the content description to the imageview

```
android:contentDescription="imagename"
```